# findOneAndUpdate is not working in mongodb/nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, ionic3

I am trying to update a Record in mongodb using nodejs but it isn't working 
I am getting data on the other side and everything seems to be working but it just won't update the record

My server Side code is

```
 console.log('here',req.params.userId )
  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.userId }, {$set:req.body}, { new: true }, function (err, users) {
    if (err)
        res.send(req.params.userId);
res.json(users);
});
```

It returns a null value I don't know why.
Any Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: What does the `req.body` contains. Does it contains fields to update and their values

Comment: yes @ambianBeing

Comment: To debug it.. do u get any record when you do a simple find `User.findOne({ _id : req.params.userId })`. Even if casting is required use mongoose's own method `mongoose.Types.ObjectId('req.params.userId');`

Answer (score 0):

This is because Mongo's ObjectId() came rendered as string in req.body:

do this:

```js
console.log('here',req.params.userId )

User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.userId) }, {$set:req.body}, { new: true }, function (err, users) {
    if (err) res.send(req.params.userId);

    res.json(users);
});
```

You can require ObjectId from bson package
as I work with TypeScript the import I use is `import { ObjectId } from 'bson';` in pure javascript should be `import ObjectId = require('bson');`

Comment: Tried  objectId but now i am getting this error :   "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "BSON {}" at path "_id" for model "User"\n    .

Comment: what's the content of req.params.userId? it should be a string. also make sure you're not casting but creating a new ObjectId

Comment: req,params.userId is a string  and i am doing it like this    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: new ObjectId(req.params.userId) }, {$set:req.body}, { new: true }, function (err, users) {
  if (err) res.send(req.params.userId);

  res.json(users);
});

Comment: but still it gives me null value @OTANO

Comment: import ir from bson https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson, also make sure your dat ais ok, can you do a test on command line mongoDB ? does it work?. the correct import will be `const bson = require("bson")` and then you do `{ _id: new bson.ObjectId(stringID) }` in first argument, to continue checking you could use a simple find instead of findOneAndUpdate . Let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: new ObjectId(req.params.userId) },
  ...req.body,
  { new: true }
)
```